# LinQ how to join data from two different contexts

Tags: c#, dbcontext

I'm using query to delete some records need to be deleted from a context based on the status those ids have in another database. And if that record doesn't have that status in that external database, delete it.

The problem is that that External database is not just one, it can be many of them depending on the project handling, so I need a function in between to know which external table should I've been querying.

But, of course, I'm getting too many errors and the code has become a Frankenstein of patches I've been applying to those lines that I'd like to fix and clean and I'm not able to think the solution by my own correctly.

CODE:

```
var partnerStatus = (from p in appContext.partner
                     where p.project.project_status.Value == "Active"
                     select p)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(x => new {
                        partner = x,
                         # this function returns a status from the external db
                         # and it's the one giving me the headaches
                        statusExternal = externalContext.StatusOf(x.Id, x.project.Id).ToString()
                    });

List<partner> toDelete = (from ps in partnerStatus 
                          join prj in appContext.project on new { ps.statusExternal, ps.project.Id } equals new { prj.project_status.Value, prj.Id } into aux
                          from pp in aux.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          where pp.Id == null
                          select ps.partner).ToList();

appContext.partner.RemoveRange(toDelete);
```

Can you help me to see the light in here?